# Duplicate dominating parents when using Deterministic Crowding in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

This is the pseudocode for using *deterministic crowding*:

```
for _ in (0, ..., n/2):
    p1, p2 = random_individual(), random_individual()
    c1 = mutate(crossover(p1, p2))
    c2 = mutate(crossover(p2, p1))

    if d(p1, c1) + d(p2, c2) < d(p1, c2) + d(p2, c1):
        population.add(winner_of(p1, c1))
        population.add(winner_of(p2, c2))
    else:
        population.add(winner_of(p1, c2))
        population.add(winner_of(p2, c1))
```

where `d` is a function that determines the difference between two individuals.

The question is:  *Do I end up with duplicate individuals in the new population* if an individual gets selected two times as one of parents, and wins over its child both times?

Comment: Is `d` using the _fitness_ function, i.e., is `d(p,q)` the same as `fitness(p) - fitness(q)`?

Comment: There is always a risk of ending up with duplicates in the pool.  How you choose to deal with this is up to you (there are pros and cons).  I usually filter out all duplicates and so that I have room for a higher number of (distinct) individuals.  However, that obviously decreases the average fitness, but on the other hand it means a greater span.

Comment: @PålGD No. `d` is Hamming Distance. The number of different genes in two individuals. If two individuals have nothing in common, `d` will be at its maximum. If two individuals have same genes, `d` will be 0.